# Getting different values with .width() function after .appendChild()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` on my `HTML` file in which I create more `divs` inside of it via `Javascript`.

Here is the `Javascript` & `JQuery` code that I use to create the divs inside their parent div:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById('container');

    for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
       var div = document.createElement("div");
       div.setAttribute("id", "div" + i);
       div.innerHTML = i; 
       div.classList.add("square");
       parentDiv.appendChild(div);
       var widthDiv = $('#div' + i).width();
       console.log(widthDiv); //It returns 499 for the first element
    }
}
```

The container div is a `flex` container and their childs are also `flex`. If I check on the console of `Google Chrome` when the page is loaded, for example, `$('#div0').width()`, I get the value of `100` which is the correct value.

Why am I getting different values if I am trying to retrieve the value of `width` of the element that I have just append to its parent? How can I fix it?

**P.S:** I think it is something related that the elements are not append before I try to read their property but then I do not understand why they return me a different value intead of null or 0.

**EDIT:** As the comments below asked, I tried to simplify my code as much as possible:

**HTML** code:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**CSS** code:

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
}
#container{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:blue;
}
.square{
    flex: 1 0 20%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you got the source html/css or a link?

Comment: Do share a executable demo of fiddle...

Comment: Please update your HTML along with jQuery/JS, using fiddle.

Comment: @Rayon I tried to simplify my code as much as possible but I could not know how to add JQuery on a JSFiddle example. I just paste the code on the question.

Comment: With is being added up by `width-of-container`/`total columns`.. I am not `css` expect but I reckon `flex` is culprit...As it is working fine with [`float`](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/u3ohh8ad/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why this code is displaying different values for the widths?

In fact here you are using `display:flex` with your divs, and they *don't have a fixed width* so for each one **the width will be the box width + the remaining width in the container**, that's why you always get the values :

```
598
299
199
149
120
```

For each elements in a row, you can see it in the console.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var parentDiv = document.getElementById('container');

  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("id", "div" + i);
    div.innerHTML = i;
    div.classList.add("square");
    parentDiv.appendChild(div);
    var widthDiv = $('#div' + i).width();
    console.log(widthDiv); //It returns 499 for the first element
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.square {
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Explanation:**

And you are appending the div in your loop so each itaeration, the available width will be decreasing and each created element will fill this width, so that explains the different values you got.

---

**Reference:**

If you take a look at **[the MDN CSS flex specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)** you can see that:

> The flex CSS property is a shorthand property specifying the ability of a flex item to alter its dimensions to fill available space.

Comment: Then how can I get the real values of my divs as if I check it directly on the console?

Comment: Real values? In fact you are not giving them any width so the width is proportiaonl here and it will be the `width-of-container/total columns in each row`, so to get real width you will need to do this after creating all elements.

Comment: I mean, for example, if you run your example, the div0 has a width of 132 pixels but it retrieves to you 660 if you use `console.log` function. 132 pixels are the pixels that it has in the moment that you run your code. How can I get this value instead of 660? Because if I use on the console of Google Chrome `$('div0').width()` it retrieves to me 132px.

Comment: With your last update now I saw where the problem is. So maybe after append all childs I should iterate through all the elements to get their real widths, right?

Comment: Yes that's what I was saying. Make two different loops, the first for craeting elements and the second to get their widths.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand you before. With your last update I got the problem and how to fix it. Thank you very much, you made me clarify my mind.